# "Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError" when onTap() is called

Tags: flutter, dart, nosuchmethoderror

I'm new to flutter and have recently started working on my first flutter project.

The idea is that when the user touches the button / image it should play a sound.

I'm using android studio to create the app.
I have imported a package called
[Audioplayers](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers) to help play the audio.

When I run the code, the app is built and it displays the image, but when I tap on the image, it gives me an error that I'm unable to resolve:

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'position' was called on null
```

This is the code:

```
MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.black,
     body: Center(
       child: GestureDetector(
         onTap: () {
           AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
           audioPlayer.setVolume(1.0);

           playLocal() async {
             int result = await audioPlayer.play(
                 'path/to/mp3',
                 isLocal: true);
           }
         },
         child: Image(
           image: AssetImage('assetsproj/images/PngItem_4931119.png'),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   ),
 ),
```

This is the error:

```
E/flutter (11532): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'position' was called on null.
E/flutter (11532): Receiver: null
E/flutter (11532): Tried calling: position
E/flutter (11532): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (11532): #1      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapDown (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:456:28)
E/flutter (11532): #2      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkDown (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256:5)
E/flutter (11532): #3      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.didExceedDeadline (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:227:5)
E/flutter (11532): #4      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.didExceedDeadlineWithEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:493:5)
E/flutter (11532): #5      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.addAllowedPointer.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:446:40)
E/flutter (11532): #6      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
E/flutter (11532): #7      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (11532): #8      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter (11532): #9      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
E/flutter (11532): #10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
E/flutter (11532): #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (11532): #12     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:949:23)
E/flutter (11532): #13     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter (11532): #14     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)
E/flutter (11532): #15     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
E/flutter (11532): #16     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
E/flutter (11532):
```

I'm not sure why I get this error.

Comment: Is `playLocal()` is a method? Try move it out and see.

Comment: I've imported a package for audio and its git page specified i use the above method to play audio from local assets.

Comment: Don't you need to add the mp3 as an asset rather than pointing to its location on disk?

Comment: you can not directly add link of your folder. add in project and then specify that file in pubspec.yaml file

Comment: I did add them as assets in pubspec.yaml and also tried changing the path to the local path but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to solve the error by importing a few new packages and removing the old package.

Imported `PositionTapDetector` and replaced `Gesturedetector` with it.

Changed `Audioplayer` to `Audio_Cache`

But I think the main problem was the `playLocal()` method which plays audio from the devices location and not the asset folder.

So the final code is

```
child: PositionedTapDetector(
            onTap: (center) {
                  AudioCache player = AudioCache();
                  player.play('audio/movie_1.mp3');
              },
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/PngItem_4931119.png'),
            ),
```